# How to show the relationship of a requirement with the operation of satifying class?

Tags: uml, relationship, class-diagram, class-method

As the title of question shows, I want to display the relationship of the requirements of a class with the method of that class that satisfies the requirement(s).
for example, suppose that we have a class named **myClass** that is supposed to satisfy **Req1**, **Req2**, and **Req3**.
In class diagram, I connected the three requirements to the **myClass** through **satisfy** relationship.
**myClass** has three methods named **method1**, **method2**, and **method3** that each method satisfies **Req1**, **Req2**, and **Req3** respectively.

now, how can I show (and in which UML diagram) that **method1**, **method2**, and **method3** satisfies **Req1**, **Req2**, and **Req3** respectively?

Comment: Maintaining requirement traceability relationships in this level of detail is usually not cost effective. It takes a lot of time to draw these relationships and to maintain them when something changes in the operations. Furthermore, the relationships are not reliable unless some system can generate them for you, from the source code or from whatever specifies the operation behavior. It usually saves time to investigate the impact of a requirement change ad hoc, instead of maintaining all traceability relationships.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl, yeah you are right, in Agile development you don't need to have this relationship but what if you have to follow V_Cycle?

Comment: The V-model prescribes that requirements and design elements have traceability relationships, but you can do this on the class level instead of on the operation level.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl, We have no problem using class model because we can easily trace the requirements that are satisfied by the class. But as the title of question says I'd like to know which operation of class is satisfying which requirement(s).

Comment: Do you want that to save time, to increase software quality or just because it's required by your superiors?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl, I want software quality. We produce automotive ECUs and we need to be sure about all requirements to be satisfied correctly and we need to trace requirements carefully because some changes in requirement might happen in future by OEM.

Comment: Maybe it works in your case, but in my experience, it only reduces software quality. Why? Because the traces are maintained manually and thus are error prone. Even if they are perfect in the beginning, omissions or false traces creep in over time. If a requirement changes and your impact analysis relies on those traces, you may miss something. Based on that imperfect impact analysis, bugs may be introduced.

Answer (score 2):

The following ways come to mind, none preferred:

- The most general way would be to attach a note to a «satisfies» (or what ever stereotype you like) Dependency where you specify the name of the operation.

[image]

- Instead of a note you could per convention name to connector as the operation. This convention must be documented elsewhere in the modeling domain.

[image]

- Some tools (like Enterprise Architect) allow to position connectors towards attributes/operations. This is no standard, but in the tool's domain it would be a way to pin the «satisfies».

[image]

Comment: I'm using Enterprise Architect and yes we can connect the requirement to a specific method of a class. There are two notes: the first is that the direction of <<satisfies>> relationship should be from class(method) to requirement(s) in my perspective. The second is that although we can connect the requirement(s) to method(s) of a class in EA but in the Traceability window(in EA) we cannot see that which requirements have been attached to which methods.

Comment: Yeah, that direction I noticed after sketching and was too lazy to fix it. So I added the note. Regarding the traceability: yes, that's because it's not a basic UML thing. It's only a graphical addition. Not sure whether using the name would help here.

Comment: I fixed the direction. Regarding the traceability the above is only visible in diagrams. There might be a way to use queries. I could try an answer on that if you open a EA-centric question.

Comment: What do you mean by "open a EA-centric question"? You mean creating another question? or adding EA tag to the question? I added EA tag to the question.

Comment: Open a new question for showing the above in EA. I don't have that answer right now but would investigate... I removed the tag here since I answered generally.

Comment: I’ll probably ask a dumb question: what is a “requirement” from an UML perspective ? Is this some kind of classifier ? And what is their relationship to use-cases ?

Comment: Can I use the last diagram for new question?

Comment: Sure. That wouldn't be an issue. You might even reference this question.

Comment: @Christophe UML does not know requirement (I haven't looked, just out of the stomach; will check later). But there are a couple of profiles (SysML as well IIRC) which define requirements as stereotype of metaclass Class. The above is EA's rendering of an internal stereotype definition. P.S. There's only one mention of requirement on p. 680 for the «trace».